# Setting up failover for dockerized Zabbix instances (not Docker Swarm)

Tags: docker, failover, zabbix

We are currently using Zabbix as our monitoring solution. Our Zabbix server is set up as a Docker container. We're not using Docker Swarm or any other cluster management technique; just deploying individual containers on different hosts with docker-compose.

In order to increase reliability, we want to deploy a second server, on a different host machine, with automatic failover. Unfortunately:

- All the documentation we can find about setting up failover for Zabbix (e.g. [this](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/high_availability) or [this](https://ericsysmin.com/2016/02/18/configuring-high-availability-ha-zabbix-server-on-centos-7/)) assumes Zabbix is running as a service and depends on controlling it in ways that will not work for a Docker container
- If there is any documentation on how to set up virtual IP/heartbeat-based failover for containerized services (in general, not Zabbix specifically), it is lost in the flood of results for how to set up failover using Docker Swarm or how to set up failover *for* Docker Swarm
- There does not seem to be any documentation available on the subject of setting up failover for containerized Zabbix specifically

Can anyone direct me to instructions on how to do this? Zabbix-specific or otherwise? I can't be the first person to need to set up failover between two containers that aren't linked by Swarm.

Comment: I think you may want to research Kubernetes. You don't want Swarm, but you will need _some_ sort of a cluster manager anyway. Your biggest problem will be implementing HA for the Zabbix database.

Comment: We don't - or at least shouldn't - need cluster management software, since we don't actually have a cluster. We just have a handful of separate Docker hosts, each managed individually.
All I'm looking for here is a way for two containerized services on fixed, separate hosts to check on each other's status so they can take over if the other goes down.

Comment: I'm afraid you're oversimplifying the problem. Your future two Zabbixes do form a cluster, whether you want it or not, and something (a cluster manager) should be in charge of "checking on statuses and taking over".  In addition to that, you'll need to take care of the "split brain" scenario (with only two members that's guaranteed to happen), virtual IP addresses, synchronization of the databases, and other things. You can try to roll your own solution for what is basically a cluster manager, or you can take an existing product and use it. Your choice.